# Is it possible to speed up Classify with PerformanceGoal->"Quality"

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning

I want to reproduce a Kaggle's python version's result of MNIST.

PCA+SVM with accuracy=0.98 on test set.

By default in Classify, with SVM method, I get a result accuracy 0.9675 and now I get 0.975

And I want to know what's the best result of PerfanceGoal->"Quality" in the whole dataset.

The problem is it's too too too slow, 100 times time consumption of python's version, my cpu is intel i7-7700k-desktop-version. In running Classify with MNIST full dataset, the CPU usage and Memory usage is low about 30%.

Yes, the dataset is big, size of training data is 60000.
So, the key problem is the calculating speed.
Though, I know we can use a subset to do experiment, but I want to know is there some magic way to speed up the performance of training-speed also keep quality of SVM or NeuralNetwork in Classify?

I know in NetTrain we can use GPU, it's cool.
I want to know even set all parameters, options, is it possible to speed up the performance of training like `Compile`,`Parallel` or `TargetDevice->GPU`, or something else

Question1: is there a global method to speed up Classify.

Question2: is there an algorithm-related method with Classify-SupportVectorMachine. If the answer of question 1 is No, do you know what's the most time-comsuming options or parameters in SVM and without importance of improving accuracy.

[my notebook](https://github.com/HyperGroups/MathematicaMachineLearning/blob/master/MNIST/SVM/SVD%2BSVM%40acc_0.979.nb)

Comment: One thing you can do is to run `cl = Classify[data, opts]` with a smaller dataset and then generate 2 classifiers: 1 without `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` and one with. After than you examine `cl[[1]]` to see what classify actually did and how the `PerformanceGoal` influenced the creation of the classifier function. Once you know that, you can forget about specifying the `PerformanceGoal` option completely and just put in the `Method` you need and taylor it.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit yes, that's a workflow in tune parameters, I want to know even set all parameters, options, is it possible to speed up the performance of training like Compile or TargetDevice->GPU, or something else.

Comment: It might help to post the code you use and the timings you are seeing.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using a singular values decomposition explicitly as a PCA-type dimension reduction, then letting the SVM classifier loose on the result. The code below is adapted from a related method I've used elsewhere. The SVD part subtracts the mean of each vector to zero-center, and also adds a "normalizing" component to each vector obtained from the SVD step.

First step is to obtain all the images.

```
trainingBytes = Import[
   "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
   , "Byte"];
trainingImages = Map[Image[Partition[#, 28]] &,
   Partition[Drop[trainingBytes, 16], 28^2]];
testBytes = Import[
   "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
   , "Byte"];
testImages = Map[Image[Partition[#, 28]] &,
   Partition[Drop[testBytes, 16], 28^2]];
trainingLabels = Drop[Import[
    "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"
    , "Byte"], 8];
testLabels = Drop[Import[
    "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"
    , "Byte"], 8];
```

The code below will preprocess using SVD, build the classifier using SVM, and also process query images using the right-side orthogonal matrix given by the SVD step. I leave the `PerformanceGoal` option to default setting. Changing it to "Quality" will make this quite slow.

```
nearestImages[ilist_, vals_, keep_] :=
 Module[
  {idata, images = ilist,
   topvecs, uu, ww, vv, udotw, norms},
  idata = Map[ImageData, images];
  topvecs = Map[Flatten, idata];
  topvecs = Map[# - Mean[#] &, topvecs];
  {uu, ww, vv} =
   SingularValueDecomposition[topvecs, keep];
  udotw = uu.ww;
  norms = Map[Sqrt[#.#] &, udotw];
  udotw = udotw/norms;
  udotw = Join[udotw, Transpose[{Log[norms]}], 2];
  {Classify[udotw -> vals, Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"], vv}]

processInput[ilist_, vv_] :=
 Module[
  {idata, images = ilist,
   topvecs, tdotv, norms},
  idata = Map[ImageData, images];
  topvecs = Map[Flatten, idata];
  topvecs = Map[# - Mean[#] &, topvecs];
  tdotv = topvecs.vv;
  norms = Map[Sqrt[#.#] &, tdotv];
  tdotv = tdotv/norms;
  tdotv = Join[tdotv, Transpose[{Log[norms]}], 2];
  tdotv]
```

Now we run it, with the setting to retain the largest 40 singular values.

```
keep = 40;
AbsoluteTiming[{nf, vv} =
   nearestImages[trainingImages,
    trainingLabels, keep];]
AbsoluteTiming[testvecs =
   processInput[testImages, vv];]

(* Out[10]= {285.201, Null}

Out[11]= {0.624939, Null} *)
```

We can speed up the lookup step using coarse-grained parallelization.

```
guesses[nf_, tvecs_] := 
 ParallelMap[nf, tvecs, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]
correct[guess_, actual_] /;
  Length[guess] == Length[actual] :=
 Count[guess - actual, 0]

AbsoluteTiming[guessed = guesses[nf, testvecs];]
correct[guessed, testLabels]

(* Out[20]= {316.824, Null}

Out[21]= 9834 *)
```

We somewhat exceed 98% recognition in this way.

Comment: Glad to know the trick of the use of `Log`, also `ParallelMap` which I haven't try.  See my edit, I add an notebook link in my GitHub, in that notebook I use DimensionReduce by LatentSemanticAnalysis which is based on SVD I think.